# Switch on system at a particular time from shutdown

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I am looking for a software which can power on my Windows 7 desktop at a particular time, say 5am. I tried Auto Shutdown and Poweron software, but for some reason it is not able to switch on the system.

If it is not possible to switch on automatically from Shutdown state, power on from hibernate state will do.

Comment: possible to do this from the motherboard itself from the "off" state, what is the motherboard the computer uses? or what computer is it exactally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motherboards these days will support wake up timers by the OS. WOL isn't necessary to implement this.

Go into Control Panel and Select **Change plan settings** next to the power plan you want use.

**Select Change settings** that are currently unavailable then **look for set allow wake timers**. Enable it.

Then you can go into Task Scheduler to wake your computer.

The tasks in Task Scheduler have an option to explicitly allow "wake the computer to run this task." Unfortunately, there is no way to find out what tasks currently have this checked.  There use to be a VBscript floating around that would do it, I'll have to dig that up later.

Comment: Though, I would like the system to be in shutdown state, I guess it's not possible. Your method works when I put the computer in sleep mode. That works for me for now. My purpose is to operate my desktop remotely, shutdown the system at night, and make it power on in the morning the next day. I hope sleep takes minimal power.

Comment: Does this also work when the system is in hibernated?

Comment: Depends on your motherboad. I'm not sure of the exact requirements.  For the record, the Intel H55 I'm running works hibernated.

Answer (score 0):

Some motherboards include this feature in their ROM-based setup program so it might be worth seeing if you can press a key to enter setup (often DEL, F2 or ESC) while the system is starting and have a look around.

If your motherboard or network adaptor supports 'Wake on Lan' (WOL) then you might be able to do this from your router; the How-to Geek has a bit on this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/70084/how-to-schedule-your-computer-to-wake-up-at-specific-times-with-dd-wrt/

If you have another PC that stays on you could schedule it to run a free WOL app (Google will help here) at the desired time.